# Changing color in mathmode in LyX

Tags: lyx, color

I know there are `\color` and `\textcolor` commands for changing colors in mathmode. However, these commands have two arguments, so when I enter them in LyX, the first argument "swallows" the command and I can't enter the text whose color I want to change.

How do I change color in mathmode within LyX?

Comment: `\color` only has one argument.

Comment: Can you please make a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac ? I know it takes time, but it would be appreciated if you took the time to help make LyX better.

Comment: I think this was previously reported as: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/5269

Comment: @scottkosty seems that this is still open? Is there a built in solution other than pasting the entire code or creating a custom macro?

Comment: @UrYa'ar unfortunately I don't know another workaround :(.

Answer (score 7):

```
\textcolor{red}{$y=f(x)$}
```

can also be used inside the math mode.

[image]

Comment: Note that this works for LyX if you paste it in all at once. Specifically, copy the LaTeX, start a math inset, paste.

Comment: @scottkosty is correct. Instead of copying and pasting each time, I copy and paste `\textcolor{#1}{#2}` once into a macro with two arguments. If you only need red, make a one argument macro and paste in `\textcolor{red}{#1}`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about LyX, but in LaTeX, adding colors in math expressions does work the same way it does in normal text, for example:

```
\( {\color{red} \frac{1}{4}} + {\color{blue} \frac{2}{4}} = {\color{green} \frac{3}{4}} \)
```

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWPQL.png]

Might not work in LyX though.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 0):

A solution which I discovered thanks to [Juan Pablo Yunda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-THtcKlqjng):

1. Go to Tools
2. Go to Preferences
3. Go to Editing
4. Go to Shortcuts
5. Create new shortcut. For example, say you want to use colour blue. The function for the shortcut would be 'math-insert \textcolor{blue}{}}'
6. Pick a key you want to use (e.g. I use **Alt+M C *Initial letter of the color***, e.g. **Alt+M C B** for blue)
7. Press Apply