# Easiest way to change colour of formulae in LyX

Tags: math-mode, formatting, lyx, color

My formulae (in mathmode) have a few terms, and I want to change the colour of each term so that I can see multiple colours in one single line. Are there any shortcut keys or easy ways to do this? Now, I will need to copy the part I want, paste it in the textmode so I can see the LaTeX code for that part, and then change it to, i.e. `{\color{red} expression}`, and finally paste it back to the mathmode so the expression can change colour itself. Are there simpler ways to do this?

Comment: I don't understand you mean, but `{\color{red} x}` works fine, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
${\color{red}x} + {\color{blue}y} = \color{green}z$
\end{document}`. You can also use `\textcolor{red}{x}`.

Comment: I mean now I have to type the code for colouring the text, which is a bit inconvenient. I wonder if lyx offers any 'efficient' ways to do this, like by just clicking a few buttons or shortcut keys (like in MS word). Just like when I want to insert a matrix, I can just click a few buttons to do that without having to know the code for that, unlike when I use some other more traditional latex editors. I want to know if changing colour is also something that can be done easily.

Comment: I was suspecting that you were using LyX, but you *didn't say so*. It is a rather crucial piece of information. (Most people here don't use LyX.)

Comment: Related: [Changing color in mathmode in LyX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281645) and http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/5269